# what's the right way of a plugin setcookie() in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, setcookie

I code like this:

```
public function register() {
    add_action('init', array($this, 'cookie_init'));
}
private function cookie_init() {
    if (!isset($_COOKIE['test_key'])) {
        setcookie('test_key', 'test_value', time() + 3600, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN);
    }
}
```

It works. However,I want to update the value elsewhere. There's an error when setcookie is called ofcourse(some headers have been sent already).Another question is how to add a new cookie k-v when needed(NOT for the init point)

Thanks for any suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

You should probably factorise your code more.
You can create a function like this :

```
function setMyCookie($key, $value) {
    if (!isset($_COOKIE[$key])) {
        setcookie($key, $value, time() + 3600, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN);
    }
}
```

This function does not need to be in the WordPress Class engine.

You can otherwise create that function as a static member so you can call it everywhere.

PS: I am not a Wordpress expert but this does not seem to really be a Wordpress issue but more a PHP developing style issue.

Comment: I think it's neither a Wordpress issue nor a PHP developing style issue,the code i listed above is just an example. Wp has its own style which developers should follow to manage customizing cookie however I haven't got it. Thanks.